# Randomising order of TextStim in an amended list/ finding the index of an iteration in a loop (Psychopy )

Tags: python, list, psychopy

To get to the point, I have amended 120 different colour TextStim (different coloured word) items to a list called 'trials'. I will be looping through 'trials' to present these stimuli one by one. However, they have been amended to this list in an order according to the loop I used. I ideally need them to be randomised in order for when they are presented. 
I have tried:

import random

trials = random.shuffle(trials)

but all I get is TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable... I think it has something to do with the fact that the type of stimulus in the list is stored as the wrong variable type. for the same reason when I try to find the trial number of each presentation (for c in trials:  ...  trialnum = len(c)) so I can store the trial number along with the response, I get a message about it not being iterable in this form. Basically I feel that these two issues are related in some fundamental way.

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks!

Comment: Please paste the code where you create `trials`. It looks like it is not a list but rather `None`. Have you tried printing `trials` just prior to shuffling to confirm this?

Comment: trials = [] ... .... .... ..... ....
for a in range(0, 15):
    trials.append(redcong)
    trials.append(blucong)
    trials.append(grecong)
    trials.append(yelcong)

... .... .... .... ... ....

for b in range(0, 5):
    trials.append(redincongb)
    trials.append(redincongg)
    trials.append(redincongy)
    trials.append(bluincongr)
    trials.append(bluincongg)
    trials.append(bluincongy)
    trials.append(greincongr)
    trials.append(greincongb)
    trials.append(greincongy)
    trials.append(yelincongr)
    trials.append(yelincongb)
    trials.append(yelincongg)

Comment: where each of the appended items e.g. redcong is a stimulus type and the loop dictates how many of each type of stimuli are in the final list.

Comment: and sorry yes to answer your question, when I print the list, it comes out in an unfamiliar format like this:  '<psychopy.visual.text.TextStim object at 0x03C02F10>' rather than the actual variable name e.g. 'redcong'. obviously this is the issue but I have no idea how to go about solving it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because `random.shuffle` shuffles in place and returns `None` (that's why you get an error about `NoneType`), so do

```py
random.shuffle(pairs)
```

instead of

```py
pairs = random.shuffle(pairs)
```

As a general comment, you would not generate a lot of TextStims but rather generate one and then update that when you run the experiment. It looks like you're doing a Stroop experiment or something like it. So do something like this:

```py
# General setup
import random
from psychopy import visual, event
win = visual.Window()

# A TextStim and five of each word-color pairs
stim = visual.TextStim(win)
pairs = 5 * [('blue', 'blue'), ('red', 'blue'), ('green', 'yellow'), ('red','red')]
random.shuffle(pairs)

# Loop through these pairs
for pair in pairs:
    # Set text and color
    stim.text = pair[0]
    stim.color = pair[1]

    # Show it and wait for answer
    stim.draw()
    win.flip()
    event.waitKeys()
```

Comment: that's really great thanks! do you know anything about getting round the: 
SyntaxError: can't assign to literal error message? I'm trying to print out the colour the key press refers to, not the key itself but when I try to assign it.......    'f' = 'red'............... I get that error message. thanks for your time

Comment: Do `f='red'`. You can't assign a value to a string. Assign it to a variable.